# Group MongoDB data by date of night

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

A MongoDB 3.4 collection stores sensor information containing a timesamp as an ISODate field.

The sensor information need to be processed differently whether they are at *day* or *night*, where *night* means >= 20.00 (8 pm) and < 08.00 (8 am). I can easily use [`$hour`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) to check if a measurement is to *day* or *night*.

By requirement all measures at night belong to the date the night started, i.e. the date of a measurement at 21.00 would fit, while one need to subtract one day from a measurement at 03.00.

I want to do an aggregation for all *night* measures (a `$match` step filters out all day measures, that's not a problem) and group by the date of that night. Do you have any idea how I could do this? I thought about using a `$project` step and get the time information, but am not sure how to generate a valid `_id` I could use for the group operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filtering part can be done using the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline which also serves to create the field to be used in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** `_id` key and a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline. The backbone of such is the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator which will evaluate the condition in the requirements to produce the desired date.

A single **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline would suffice but since you also need the logic to group the filtered documents with, you might as well use the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline to create the field that has such logic.

The following example demonstrates this concept:

```
db.sensors.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "yearMonthDay": {
                "$cond": [
                    { /* check if date hour is less than 8 */
                        "$lt": [
                            { "$hour": "$date" },
                            8
                        ]
                    },
                    { /* subtract one day from a measurement at < 08:00 */
                        "$dateToString": { 
                            "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                            "date": {
                                "$subtract": [
                                    "$date",
                                    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                                ]
                            }
                        } 
                    },
                    {  /* else return actual date */
                        "$dateToString": { 
                            "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                            "date": "$date" 
                        } 
                    }
                ]
            },
            "isNight": { 
                "$or": [
                    { "$gte": [ { "$hour": "$date" }, 21  ] },
                    { "$lt": [ { "$hour": "$date" }, 8  ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "isNight": true } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$yearMonthDay",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

---

A more verbose approach involves using the **[`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/)** case expression in place of the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** as follows (thanks to [@Styvane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100115/)):

```
db.sensors.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "yearMonthDay": {
                 "$switch": {
                    "branches": [
                        { 
                            "case": { "$lt": [ { "$hour": "$date" }, 8 ] }, 
                            "then": { /* subtract one day from a measurement at < 08:00 */
                                "$dateToString": { 
                                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                                    "date": {
                                        "$subtract": [
                                            "$date",
                                            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                                        ]
                                    }
                                } 
                            } 
                        },
                        { 
                            "case": { "$gte": [ { "$hour": "$date" }, 8 ] }, 
                            "then": {  /* return actual date */
                                "$dateToString": { 
                                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                                    "date": "$date" 
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }                   
            },
            "isNight": { 
                "$or": [
                    { "$gte": [ { "$hour": "$date" }, 21  ] },
                    { "$lt": [ { "$hour": "$date" }, 8  ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "isNight": true } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$yearMonthDay",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: How about replacing `$cond` with `$switch`?

Comment: Same thing really, depends on how verbose the OP wants the query otherwise I believe performance-wise that won't have much impact, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right, I am not trying to be pedantic here but it also makes your intention clear and after all you doing this in MongoDB 3.4:)

Comment: Cheers @Styvane :) Always appreciate your input